# Ubuntu 13.04 is slow on my PC

Tags: unity, 13.04, performance

I have recently installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my PC, and it's quite slow. I'm not sure what is causing the trouble, but it looks to me like it's Unity, because all the applications take a long time to start.

I have an Intel Core 2 Duo 2.2 GHz CPU and 1.5GB RAM. I don't have any extra graphics or video card installed. And from what I have read I know that Unity uses a lot of GPU if there is a GPU installed. So if this is the cause of my poor system performance, would switching to a new desktop environment be advisable? Do you have any other suggestions for how to improve my system's performance?

Comment: What evidence have you to blame unity? I think you can salvage this question if you have evidence against unity, and then rephrase it to be about optimising unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might try to turn Ubuntu into Xubuntu by following the instructions you find at this link:
https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/alternative

Answer (score 1):

try Xubuntu 13.04 or Lubutu 13.04, this distros is very fast, because lightweigt Desktop Environment

Comment: If you wanna stay on ubuntu 13.04, also you may be disable effects in compiz or change Unity 3d on Unity 2d...

Comment: At least by reading the following post, Unity 2D seems not to be available on Ubuntu 13.04: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2143639&p=12640796&viewfull=1#post12640796

Answer (score 0):

It's not very much RAM for running Ubuntu with Unity, my laptops memory uses more memory than that most of the time.
Does your computer use the swap partition a lot?

Comment: How much memory does your laptop use most of the time? Your answer would be improved IMO if you added this info to it.

Comment: yeah at sometime it does like for some 100 mb if its running for a long time.